# Edit MySQL table in a Symfony project hosted [SOFTACULOUS]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, alter, softaculous

I'm coding a Symfony project and I should host it on a server that make me install Symfony by Softacolous (I can't use a shell). So, I can't understand how make an edit on the online DB.
Can you help me?

Comment: What kind of edit do you want to make?

Comment: @DanieleFois Add a column that references another table.

Comment: You have to check in your cpanel for phpmyadmin and do it manually then.
You'll also have to adjust manually your entities.

Comment: @DanieleFois okay! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use cPanel's Remote MySQL to enable access from your local PC and run:

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=prod

To update your database from your code.

Also you dont need to install symfony via Softacolous, just upload your local files via ftp